# how can I work on both default and branch at same time in Hg?

Tags: windows, mercurial, merge, branch, tortoisehg

OK, I'm new to Mercurial and version control branching in general, so I may have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on here -- please be kind...  ;)

We are a small development team (2 developers) working on a project, and we have a need to implement a fairly significant change that may take weeks or months.  At the same time, the program is in daily use, so we have a need to make regular patches and fixes.

Because of the long-running nature of the significant change, I created a branch off the default branch (call it dev1).  I will want to periodically merge the changes from the default branch into the dev1 branch, for reasons that don't need to be reiterated here.  However, I do NOT want the changes from dev1 merged into the default branch until much later in the development.

I have tried several different ways to do this, but it always seems the merge affects both branches.  After the merge, if I update to the default I now have changes from dev1 merged into the source.

Can I work on both branches using the same repository?  If so, can someone please share the sequence of commands to use?  If not, it seems to me I would not be able to push the dev1 branch up to the master repo until it was finished, and that just doesn't seem right.

We are running the latest TortoiseHg for Windows, and for the most part I love the graphical tool.  However, I am perfectly willing to drop to the command line to do certain tasks when necessary.

Thanks for any help,
Dave

Comment: For anyone who might get into the situation I got into, here's how I fixed it.

Comment: Oops. Thought I could get a new line in a comment, silly me...  I cloned the corrupted repo, updated back to the dev1 branch whilst discarding all uncommitted changes, and voila!  I now have 2 separate branches.  I then wiped out my original repo and cloned from the "fixed" one. Still no clue as to how I got to the state I was in, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what sort of branch you've created.

If you have created a *named branch*, and are working in a single working directory, then you need to use one workflow, but if you have cloned your production repository, you need to use a different workflow.

#### Named branch workflow, single repo/working directory

In this case, you are using update to switch between the `default` branch and the `dev1` feature branch.

When you want to work on the `default` branch, update to it, do your bug fixes, and commit those changes. Do not merge in changes from `dev1` branch.

When you want to work on your `dev1` branch, update to it, merge in your bug fixes from the default branch, work on your feature and commit when done.

If you are working on the `dev1` branch and a colleague fixes a bug in `default` that you need, commit your work, fetch their changes, merge them in and then resume your work (there are shortcuts you can take here, but this way you can backout the merge if it gets messy)

Note: All of these assume that all of your changes are committed at the point you want to switch between `dev1` and `default` branches.

The important thing to note is that you only get the changes from your `dev1` branch in `default` when you merge them in. If you only merge `default` into `dev1` then your feature branch will keep up to date with `default` so that when you are ready to deploy the feature into the `default` branch, you can do so with one simple merge operation.

#### Unnamed branch workflow using `dev1` repo cloned from production repo

This workflow is similar, but allows you to work on the `default` and `dev1` branches simultaneously, without having to update to switch between the two.

When you want to work on the `default` branch, use the repository where the tip is your production code. Do your bug fixes, and commit those changes just as you would normally.

When you want to work on your `dev1` branch, use the repository where the tip is your dev1 feature branch. If there have been fixes in the `default` repository, pull in the changes and merge them into your clone, but do not push the merge changeset back. Only push your changeset back when you want to deploy you feature to production code. Once the changesets from `default` have been merged in, you can continue working on the feature.

If you are working on the `dev1` branch and a colleague fixes a bug in `default` that you need, commit your work, fetch their changes from your shared repository into your `default` production clone, then pull those changes down into your `dev1` feature clone, merge them in and then resume your work.

Again, the important thing to note is that you only get the changes from your `dev1` branch in `default` when you push them up to your `default` production repository. If you only pull/merge `default` changesets into the `dev1` clone then your feature branch will keep up to date with `default` so that when you are ready to deploy the feature into the `default` branch, you can do so with one simple push operation.

Comment: I am/was using named branches, thanks for the breakdown.  I believe the graphical tool didn't do what I thought it was going to do, so from now on I'll drop to the command line to do things where I can get bit...

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, both for this answer and the comment to antoher answer below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can absolutely do this with Mercurial.

First, in case it isn't clear to you (it wasn't to me for some time), there are [3 types of 'branches'](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Branch) in Mercurial:

- clone a repository
- a 'named branch' (using the `hg branch` command)
- an anonymous branch, which you can manage with bookmarks or just remembering the changeset

I'm guessing that you used the `hg branch` method. Be aware that this is often *not* what you want, because that branch name will live in the repo's history forever (well, there is the `--close-branch` option, but still...).

The essential workflow is:

- update to dev branch with `hg up devbranch`
- commit changes to dev branch
- merge with main branch via `hg merge default` or just `hg merge` as desired
- (repeat as desired)

And for working on the default branch:

- update to default branch with `hg up default`
- commit changes
- (repeat as desired)

Do NOT do this:

- update to default branch with `hg up default`
- merge with dev branch with `hg merge`

<strike>I suspect that you are using the command `hg merge` without specifying a branch name. That will merge with any other head, which may or may not be what you want.</strike>

**Edit:** The above info is probably not your issue. Your issue is probably running a merge when your current branch is the default one.

You *don't* want to run `hg merge` from your default branch.

Comment: I was very careful NOT to do the merge when default was my current branch, and still I have managed to corrupt the default branch.  I did the merge from the graphical tool, and I believe that was probably my problem.

Comment: @DaneN59 - In TortoiseHG it is easy to accidentally merge `default` into `dev1` rather than `dev1` into `default` if you use the context menu from the wrong one to initiate the merge. I suspect that's what you might be doing - I know I've done it a few times. *8') The trick is to look at the ways the link lines connect.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I must have done that without realizing it, as you said, but I *thought* I was being very careful not to...

Answer (score 1):

```
# bang on dev1
# more banging on dev1
# someone beats on default for a while
# update to dev1
hg up dev1
# bring in the changes from default
hg merge -r default
# validate successful merge
hg commit -m "merging"
```

The key is committing on dev1 when you bring changes over from default.

Note that I'm using named branches here.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  Then I updated to the default branch, and I have numerous  uncommitted changes -- from the dev1 branch.  Do I just have a broken install of TortoiseHg or what?

Comment: If you committed on the dev1-branch, and update to the default branch, and have uncommitted changes, then you did not commit everything on dev1 before you left it. If you had, the update back to default would've given you a pristine working folder.

Comment: I'll give you that, but how did I get a partial commit?  That's what is confounding me at the moment...

Comment: @Dave: you need to commit before you swap. If you are using TortoiseHG gui, I suggest avoiding that for a bit and sticking with the command line - the gui makes some decisions for you (e.g., committing as part of the merge dialog sequence).

Answer (score 1):

This sentence:

> After the merge, if I update to the default I now have changes from dev1 merged into the source.

tells me that you're doing something wrong. It is perfectly doable what you want to do, work on two branches in parallel, and merge from one to the other, without influencing both.

It is important to know that the merge is a directional merge. You merge *from* one branch *to* the other, and when you initiate the merge, you should be *on* the *to*-branch.

*directional* in the sense that the direction plays a role in the outcome. For the actual contents of the file, it doesn't matter which direction you merge, but the new merge-changeset you commit will be on the branch you was on when you initiated the merge (unless you override.)

So, update to the head of `dev1` first, then merge with `default`, and after committing, you should have a new changeset on the `dev1` branch, but `default` should be left undisturbed.

Comment: I am aware of that prerequisite, and I thought I did that. Still, I have managed to corrupt the default branch.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a tip than an answer, but...

I use this workflow a lot. I find the [Transplant](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) extension very useful for named branch workflows. TortoiseHg supports it, so you can enable it in the TortoiseHg options. It lets you cherry-pick from other branches, which is very useful - especially if you regularly commit to the wrong branch.

Comment: @DaveN59 - I wouldn't bother. `transplant` and `rebase` are (IMHO) a legacy of workflows designed to get around the limited branching capabilities in pre distributed VCS systems. A merge gives you a clear indication of the true history of the changes which you lose when you rebase or transplant changesets.

Comment: @Mark Booth - I suppose you are entitled to that opinion. How would you accomplish the task that Transplant does then using merges, ie. how do you cherry-pick using just merges... Perhaps you thought I was suggesting to ONLY use Transplant....

Comment: @Mark Booth: While I agree that `transplant` and `rebase` are not solutions for DaveN59's problem, they are still very useful extensions and not 'legacy', IMO. They are generally most useful when working with an upsteam repo that you don't have control over.